# Jhipster dynamic role based authentication

Tags: jhipster

I am very new to java. I generated an application using jhipster. It gives you role based authentication from code behind. If I want to add new role, I need to add from code behind. But I am interested in dynamic role based authentication through UI. Can you please advise how it can be done? Any reference would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Creating a new role does not require coding, however using this new role might require some coding depending on how you want to use it. Please update your question with details about how you plan to use new roles.

Comment: You can manage user roles from the UI (_Administration > User management > Edit User > Profiles_).

Answer (score 0):

1. managing roles for users

if you just want to manage user roles (no matter where the roles come from), then you can use the Administration > User Management > Edit User feature to select roles. Note, that the actual roles are coming from `/api/user/authorities`, which requests the roles from the data source.

2. managing roles

As it `Authority` is an entity, with a repository, it is possible by default to create as many roles as you wish. The point is, that JHipster doesn't provide such management from UI and API by default. Here are the steps you can do to make this possible:

- modify the `authority.csv` in `src/main/resources/config/liquibase/data` and add your custom roles there, so they are created during database creation. This is straight forward but doesn't enable dynamic management
- similar to usual entity management, or user management, create a new `@RestController` for `/api/authorities` and allow create, delete update, etc. Then, add a new authority management module with all parts, such as list view, detail view, update dialog, service, etc. This involves several manual steps, but you have a lot of example code already there. With this, you can dynamically manage roles in your application, and as in `1`, the new roles should be available for adding to the user

In both cases, the generated code from JHipster will respect the user to authority relation when creating a session for a user, who signs in. Hope this helps